# Change Value of Column Based on Criteria in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace the NaN values with a 'yes' or 'no' depending on which count is greater based on the 'first' column and if they are equal make it a 'yes'. For example this is my original dataframe.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'first':['a','a','b','c','b','c','a','c','b','a','b','c','c','d','d','d'],
                     'second':['yes','yes','no','no',np.nan,np.nan,'no','yes',np.nan,np.nan,'yes','no','no',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

test = test.sort(['first'])

test

   first second
1      a    yes
6      a     no
9      a    NaN
0      a    yes
4      b    NaN
10     b    yes
2      b     no
8      b    NaN
5      c    NaN
3      c     no
11     c     no
12     c     no
7      c    yes
14     d    NaN
15     d    NaN
13     d    NaN
```

I want my new dataframe to be this:

```
  first second
    1      a    yes
    6      a     no
    9      a    yes
    0      a    yes
    4      b    yes
    10     b    yes
    2      b     no
    8      b    yes
    5      c    no
    3      c     no
    11     c     no
    12     c     no
    7      c    yes
    14     d    NaN
    15     d    NaN
    13     d    NaN
```

Comment: You could use something like `g = test.groupby('first')['second'].value_counts()` and then use the first row of each of the groups as the `fillna` value. However, in your current example `b` doesn't conform to your logic as `b` has one `yes` and one `no`.

Comment: if its equal then it will be yes, how do i use the `fillna` to fill it in?

Comment: George, could you please post what you've tried so far?

Comment: ok, thanks.  I'll post something shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option.  Starting with your test frame

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'first':['a','a','b','c','b','c','a','c','b','a','b','c'],
                     'second':['yes','yes','no','no',np.nan,np.nan,'no','yes',np.nan,np.nan,'yes','no']})
test = test.sort(['first'])
test

    first   second
0   a       yes
1   a       yes
6   a       no
9   a       NaN
4   b       NaN
10  b       yes
8   b       NaN
2   b       no
3   c       no
5   c       NaN
11  c       no
7   c       yes
```

**Option 1**

Then some grouping followed by sorting to create a new Dataframe (testCounts).  Note: I'm sorting ascending on "second" so Yes will appear first in the group when the counts are equal.

```
s = test.groupby(['first',"second"])["first"].agg("count")
s.name = "count"
testCounts = s.reset_index().sort(["first","count","second"],ascending=[True,False,False])
testCounts
    first   second  count
1   a       yes     2
0   a       no      1
3   b       yes     1
2   b       no      1
4   c       no      2
5   c       yes     1
```

We then use boolean indexing to filter for the NaNs.  Then we map a lambda function that takes the first row of our boolean indexed testCounts

```
rowIndex = test["second"].isnull()
test.loc[rowIndex,"second"] = test["first"].map(lambda s : 
                              testCounts[testCounts["first"] == s]["second"].iloc[0])
test

    first   second
0   a       yes
1   a       yes
6   a       no
9   a       yes
4   b       yes
10  b       yes
8   b       yes
2   b       no
3   c       no
5   c       no
11  c       no
7   c       yes
```

**Option 2.**
Starting with your frame above, we group to get counts like Option 1.  Next, we create a dict by sorting, grouping and taking the first row for each group

```
s = test.groupby(['first',"second"])["first"].agg("count")
s.name = "count"
d = s.reset_index().sort(["first","count","second"],ascending=[True,False,False])
                    .groupby("first").first()["second"].to_dict()
d

{'a': 'yes', 'b': 'yes', 'c': 'no'}
```

Boolean index like before and map the dict (d) to "first"

```
rowIndex = test["second"].isnull()
test.loc[rowIndex,"second"] = test["first"].map(d)
test
    first   second
0   a       yes
1   a       yes
6   a       no
9   a       yes
4   b       yes
10  b       yes
8   b       yes
2   b       no
3   c       no
5   c       no
11  c       no
7   c       yes
```

Comment: thanks, I ran into another error 'index out of bounds' on my original dataset, i updated my 'first' column with 'd'. I think the issue is 'd' does not show up in testCounts

Comment: nevermind, i think the second option fixes that, i will keep you updated. Thanks for your help

Comment: I added Option 1 and 2 labels to clarify

Answer (score 1):

```
def replace_na(first_value):
    return test[test['first']==first_value]['second'].fillna(g[first_value].index[0])
pd.concat(map(replace_na,first_index))
```